# IIS show upgrade website for all requests

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have a temp website set up in IIS Manager (6) linked to an IP / URL, for example:
1.2.3.4 / www.someUrl.com

When that url is accessed, the temp website shows fine. 
But if someone tries to access any other file within that domain, for example:

www.someUrl.com/index.cfm?action=profile

then the upgrade website does not display.

How do I get it to show for all requests made to the domain www.someUrl.com??

Thanks

Comment: As this question is about IIS configuration, I've voted to move it to ServerFault.

Comment: where do you have the binding set up for the temp site? Can you try `Cscript.exe adsutil.vbs GET W3SVC/1/ServerBindings -s:<serverName>` and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand well you request.
But, using Application.cfc you can implements the method onRequestStart, and you can dump all information you need to your e-mail for exemple, just to see what is the problem to your script.